# How to verify a transaction status of SQLAlchemy Session

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, transactions

I want to debug my python program by verifying whether a transaction has begun or not, and the duration. Does SQLalchemy have a kind of method?

```
if session.has_transaction_begun():
    session.show_transaction_time()
```

I cannot see the MySQL status directly because I have no permission to see `information_schema`.

Comment: `information_schema` tables can be accessible even by an unprivileged user. Their information will be limited to that of the current user however. If you where using MariaDB [in_transaction](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#in_transaction) (`SELECT @@in_transaction`) as a session system variable would show the transaction has begun and [information_schema.innodb_trx](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-innodb_trx-table/) for innodb transactions in more detail.

Comment: thanks @danblack , Is there a MySQL replacement for @@in_transaction?

Comment: Not that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute - `is_active` on the session object which indicates if a transaction is currently active on the session. I'm not aware of any way to query the transaction active time though.

```
session.is_active
```